# asp.net view syntax and html helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

This is actually two questions in one.

First question is about the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
 @Html.LabelFor(model => model.xxx, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
 <div class="col-md-10">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.xxx , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.xxx, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand what `model => model.xxx` means, I know what it's doing but i don't know how to interpret the syntax.

the second question is, if I have - for example -

`foreach (var item in Model)`

how can I replace

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.xxx , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

with

`@Html.EditorFor(item.stringProperty , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

when I try this, it gives me errors, is there an overloaded EditorFor helper that accepts this?

thank you!

Comment: found an answer to the first half of my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10467030/html-editorform-m-lambda-syntax-in-mvc

Comment: please describe your problem more excatly. You have a list and you want to create ...what?Describe, then will be better for me and for the answer.

Comment: @W92 I have a list, and I want to display an input text box for each item in the list, but I want each text box to have text inside when its created, text from each item in the list (coming from the item's property), Thank you for the help by the way, I really appreciate it

Comment: look at my answer (after edit)

Comment: thank you for the update, give me a minute to try it

Comment: Are you wanting to post back the collection i.e. save all items at once or just post back one item?

Comment: @StephenMuecke all items at once

Comment: @StephenMuecke all items that have been modified

Comment: Then the accepted answer is not correct (only posts back one item at a time) and it also is generating duplicate ID's which is invalid html.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats true, but it gave me something I can work with, with some googling (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/551576/ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding-and-Data-Annotation) I'm able to find the specific requirement for what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One view can has 0 or 1 Model, which's sending from controller.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;}
}

public ViewResult Index()
{
    Person p = new Person() { Name = "P1", Age = 100};
    return View(p);//
}
```

if your View's name "Index" then you can use second way for View, which contain 2 parameters:
`ViewName` and `model`

```
return View("Index", model: p);
```

then in your `View` you can use the `model`, if it has been implemented that:

```
@model Person//and remember about namespace
@
{
 ...
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post))
{
     @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name); // it create input, check in F12 in your browse - then you can exactly understand.
}
```

if you want create Editor for item you must use:

```
  @Html.TextBox("YourName")
```

for example:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "controller")
{
   @Html.TextBox("YourName")
   <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
}
```

and in your `controller`Controller:

```
public ViewResult Action(string YourName)
{
     //here you got value for string YourName
     return View();
}
```

and helpfully answer's here:
[ASP.NET MVC get textbox input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-razor-get-textbox-input-value)

**Edit**, answer about exactly problem (which containt in comment below question):

*I have a list, and I want to display an input text box for each item in the list, but I want each text box to have text inside when its created, text from each item in the list (coming from the item's property)*

```
@foreach(var item in Model)
@using(Html.BeginForm("MyMethod", "Controller"))
{
   @Html.TextBox("item", item)
   <input type="submit" value="ok" />
}
```

and in your controller add `MyMethod`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult MyMethod(string item)
{
 ...
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult MyMethod(int item) //if it's an int
{
 ...
}
```

and if you want to have a better security page please read about `Html.AntiForgeryToken`:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx

```
@using(Html...())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
(...)
}
```

Comment: please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18873098/asp-net-mvc-razor-get-textbox-input-value

Comment: the text is not inside the text box when it is created, I can insert text, but I want there to be text in it already coming from my item.stringProperty

Answer (score 1):

I see you already got the answer of your first question.

For the second one, i think

```
@Html.EditorFor(item => item.stringProperty , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

will work fine

Comment: i tried this but it's not recognizing "stringProperty" as a property for some reason

Comment: yes it depends what type your model is, i tought seeing your model that you were changing from a model of type X to a model with type List<X> but you use var in your code so i don't see the type. the code i wrote works only if item is an object of a class with a "stringProperty" property

Comment: oh yea, sorry, my model is a list, so for each item in my list

Comment: @Abdul Ahmad please look at the answer below. read link from comment